# IOS Swift SpriteKit Scaling Entire Views According to Frame Size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite, scaling

I would like the scenes of my game in SpriteKit to appear differently sized depending on the size of the device. Right now I am manually resizing and positioning some of my nodes with an 'if' statement checking for frame size, but unfortunately I cannot do this for all of my sprites due to the mechanics of my game (I am detecting collisions based off of the positions of my nodes,  not by using PhysicsBodies. If I were to change the size of the nodes, these collisions would not be detected).

Is there a way to scale the appearance of the view according to the device size instead of actually scaling the sprites themselves (i.e. the view would stretch out to fit frame size but in reality the sprites would actually be the same size)? Is this something I would achieve by changing the SKSceneScaleModes from .ResizeFill (the one I am currently using)?

Comment: important to note that frame.width/height is different then the view.bounds.width/height

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is an easy way to fix my problem, nor do I believe that the solution I was looking for exists. This is how I fixed my problem:

1. First, I changed my game mechanics. I've learned that when you are going about designing and initially planning out your game, you have to really focus on making your game both easily expandable and universal. The way that I had my game first set up was quite limited.
2. I figured out how I wanted to scale my game and set up my own little system (not really my 'own', its probably a pretty common setup):

   ```
   var scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
   var skView = self.view! as SKView
   scene.size = skView.frame.size
   var scale = self.frame.size.height / 736
   ```

Then I just set the scale to my nodes like so:

```
self.titleText.setScale(scale)
```

First, I am setting the size of the current scene as the size of the frame size of the skView. With that, I am creating a scale factor by dividing the size of the scene by the frame size of an iPhone 6 plus. The sprites will now appear at a scale factor of 1 on the iPhone 6 plus and downscale from there.

Anyways, I know this explanation wasn't perfect and that there is probably a more efficient way of doing this. I am relatively new to SpriteKit and have a lot to learn, but I didn't want to leave this question unanswered on the off chance that somebody stops by here. Thanks, and feel free to message me if you have any questions or I messed up somewhere.